# Elasticsearch query for unique data count

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to query the elasticsearch to get the unique ip count by devices from a bucket?
The bucket data are in the following format

```
{
    "request_time": 1651545553544,
    "cp_code": "1179526",
    "client_ip": "190.122.XXX.189",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
    "device": "Chrome",
    "stream_key": "ymty1j6r",
    "bytes": 1242,
    "country": "DO"
}

{
    "request_time": 1651545553653,
    "cp_code": "1179526",
    "client_ip": "190.122.XXX.189",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
    "device": "Chrome",
    "stream_key": "ymty1j6r",
    "bytes": 2824933,
    "country": "DO"
}

{
    "request_time": 1651545545132,
    "cp_code": "1179526",
    "client_ip": "190.122.XXX.189",
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
    "device": "Chrome",
    "stream_key": "ymty1j6r",
    "bytes": 2821788,
    "country": "DO"
}
{
    "request_time": 1651545465646,
    "cp_code": "1179526",
    "client_ip": "89.187.XXX.161",
    "user_agent": "Xtream-Codes IPTV Panel Pro",
    "device": "Other",
    "stream_key": "ymty1j6r",
    "bytes": 2807496,
    "country": "US"
}

{
    "request_time": 1651545482284,
    "cp_code": "1179526",
    "client_ip": "89.187.XXX.161",
    "user_agent": "Xtream-Codes IPTV Panel Pro",
    "device": "Other",
    "stream_key": "ymty1j6r",
    "bytes": 2813754,
    "country": "US"
}
```

Which aggregation method should I use to get the result in the following format directly from elasticsearch?

```
device|unique_ip_count
chrome|50
firefox|10
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [`terms` bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `device` field and a [`cardinality` metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) on the `client_ip` field:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "devices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "device",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_ips": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "client_ip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```